# Writing javafx-2 client which runs both on client and server side

Tags: java, swing, client-server, javafx-2

What is the recomended way to write a javafx-2 client which can be used on the server & client side (both are written in Swing) ?

Comment: The title of the post contradicts the body.  Is it Java-FX or Swing?

Comment: I have client server which are Java SE & Swing based application, now I'm trying to add some JavaFX-2 UI so that the client will display the server's UI.